# Service with AsyncTask performing a request every X time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I want to be reassured that I'm doing this the best practice way : 
I have a list which order is changing on the server, therefore, I want every 20-30 sec. to perform a request to see if there were any changes in the order. So, I've created a `Service` which is bound to the `Activity` with the `ListView`, and the service every 20-30 sec. performs a request with an `AsyncTask`. 
I chose to perform it with a `Service` because I want the list to be updated constantly, even when the application is in the background, And the `AsyncTask` is because I don't want it to be performed on the main thread. 
Is this the right way to do it?

Thank you in advance, 
Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, but your app will do a lot of unnecessary work. This will affect battery life. Besides that, according to documentation, if you use device radio, it stays full-powered at least for 20 seconds, which is also no good for battery. You have the following options:

1. Use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). It will allow you to perform update only when this is really necessary.
2. If you don't want or cannot use GCM, follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html) to optimize network access. Start with increasing the update interval (to 4 minutes at least).

Comment: I can't increase the update interval, because there should be a new information every 20-30 sec. (even less, but this is the time I can afford to my app not to be up to date, maybe i can increase it to min max, I don't know yet), this is the same reason I don't want to use GCM, because there will be constant updates. The question is given those restrictions, Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Well, if you have such restrictions, I can't suggest anything better.